# Native C++ or .NET for Business App?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, platform, windows-server-2000

Here's the deal: I'm in the process of planning a mid-sized business application that **absolutely must** support Win2k. AFAIK, official .NET support for Win2k was scrapped a while ago (IIRC, it stopped at version 2.0).

Now, I already wrote (ages ago) libraries in C++ that allow me to accomplish the end result (i.e., finish this project) just as quickly as if I was writing this application with the help of the .NET Framework -- so .NET's RAD "advantage" is almost negated.

I'm sure a lot of people here deal with business applications that need to support old OS's. So, given my library situation, what advantage(s) are there for me in using .NET over native C++ and vice versa? I'm just not sure which of the two is right for the job -- because it seems that I could use either. Then again, there's that framework support issue to deal with...

I will gladly add more information, if required.

Comment: So what's your question? Is ait about W2K support for .NET? If so, you are right - the latest versions are not supported on that platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last .NET version that runs under Windows 2000 is *.NET 2.0 SP2*. It does include the features required by *System.Core.dll* (that is part of .NET 3.5).

The answer is YES, you can use *.NET 3.5 SP1* under Windows 2000 if you're not going to use *.NET 3.0* libraries (WCF, WF, WPF, CardSpace). But you have LINQ, LINQ to XML, LINQ to SQL.

The only thing you need to do is to deploy three core *.NET 3.5 SP1* files:

- System.Core.dll
- System.Xml.Linq.dll (LINQ to XML)
- System.Data.Linq.dll (LINQ to SQL)

Disadvantages of this method (read carefully):

- Not sure whether it's permitted or forbidden by the EULA (end-user license agreement)
- This scenario is not supported by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look to see if Mono ([mono-project](http://www.mono-project.com)) works for you. i.e. runs on win2k - if it does it would allow you to port your app to MS .NET and later OS versions should the need arise later in the project. Any .NET is going to be easier than C++ IMHO :)

Answer (score 0):

The biggest difference is that you are (or your boss is) more likely to find developers to maintain your .NET code after you move on to other things.

C++ has the advantage of giving you job stability - although that might not be what you want. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, given your situtation, it boils down to what you feel more comfortable in writing.  If C++ is a comfortable language for you, do that.  It will help get you into the code and make it easier to finish.

I would also take care to keep the future in mind.  If the Win2K requirement drops that might require you to rewrite if you wrote in C++.  It might not.  Just keep it in mind while you decide how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop with .NET but set the compiler options to target the .NET 2.0 framework. If the OS gets upgraded in the near (or far) future, you can upgrade your program to target the 3.5 framework. I would go this route as it allows for easier future maintenance by others.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered Delphi? You can [download Turbo Delphi](http://www.turboexplorer.com) for free and it you can easily write code targeting Windows 2000. With Delphi, you'll get an excellent RAD (arguably better than anything you'll find in C++...unless you use C++ Builder).

Delphi creates native code, and has no runtime requirements.

Of course, the downside is if that you don't know Delphi (which is Object-Pascal) you have to familiarize yourself with a new language. However, if you know C++, you'll feel at home in Delphi in no time.